# Sequelize inner join on many to many

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm new to using ORM (Sequelize with MySQL) and can't wrap my head around implementing this query:

```sql
SELECT 
  people.*
FROM people
INNER JOIN people_tags ON people.person_id = people_tags.person_id
WHERE people_tags.tag_id = 14"
```

I am looking to retrieve people based on a tag_id.
The models are correctly defined, I am able to retrieve a tags attribute attached to a person's response.
Here is what I tried:

```js
Person.findAll({
    include: {
      model: db.tag,
      required: true,
      where: {
        person_id: db.Sequelize.col('person.person_id')
      }
    },
  })
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err
    });
  });
```

Comment: Isn't `where: {
        person_id: db.Sequelize.col('person.person_id')
      }` should be `where: {
        person_id: 14
      }`?

Comment: @Anatoly Obviously not since 14 was used as an example for the query.